# Div треугольником

Tags: css, javascript

Можно ли как-то сделать div с фиксированной высотой и шириной не прямоугольником/квадратом, а к треугольником. Чтобы незаполненная область div попросту удалялась. Нужно для кореектного отображения того что находится под div, потому как контент должен уезжать под шапку, но кусочек этой шапки своей неиспользуемой частью div перекрывает то, что под него уезжает и ессно из-за z-index туда даже не кликнуть

Comment: Да, такое можно сделать с помощью `CSS`. В этой статье Вы найдете несколько примеров: [CSS Triangle](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).

Comment: Ссылка из ответа: http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/

Answer (score 3):

Треугольником сделать нельзя. Можно сделать треугольный бордер, если это устроит.
[css3 shapes](http://www.css3shapes.com/)

```
#up-triangle {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-bottom: 120px solid green; 
   border-left: 60px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 60px solid transparent; 
}
```

UPD:

Добавьте поверх них прозрачные квадратные картинки с imageMap и будет вам счастье: активная зона любой формы и уезжание под шапку.

Comment: обьясню еще раз что мне надо. есть шапка, которая перекрывает часть контента. каждый  пост - ромб. все полотно уезжает под шапку при скролле. при наведении на ромб вылазит тултип. так вот те ромбы что попали в мертвую зону неактивны для вывода подсказки. поставить им z-index больше шапки и тогда они не уедут под нее при скролле... а должны

Comment: Добавьте поверх них прозрачные квадратные картинки с imageMap и будет вам счастье: активная зона любой формы и уезжание под шапку.

Comment: а есть какие-то ссылки на эту тему?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp - вот, например

Comment: <div class="post-item" style="position: absolute; left: 114px; top: 112px;z-index: 21000;">
<div class="tooltips" style="padding: 6px 8px; z-index: 0; opacity: 0;">lorem ipsum </div>
<div class="inner"><a class="post-fancy" href=""><img width="800" height="600" src="" class="attachment-news-page-prev wp-post-image" alt="3d-pencil-drawings-in-sketchbooks-nagai-hideyuki-4">                        </a></div></div>

Вот так выглядит пост

Answer (score 1):

Вместо div'а используй inline svg - там можно получить любую форму.

Ещё вариант - использовать clip по маске или clip-path. Для IE не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Пример с сайта [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

```css
.arrow-up {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 
 border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 border-right: 20px solid transparent;
 
 border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 60px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
 
 border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
 
 border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

([Лицензия](https://css-tricks.com/license/), если что.)