# Как создать такие треугольники с помощью псевдоэлементов?

Tags: css, sass, less

Здравствуйте,помогите,пожалуйста,создать вот такие вот треугольники...У меня,правда,нет идей. Уже гуглил на эту тему,но ничего стоящего не нашел. Изображением вставлять не канает. Нужно именно с помощью CSS.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Div треугольником](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231669/div-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradient Generator - [colorzilla.com](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

CSS triangle generator - http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b-breadcrumbs {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  background: #271E19;
  padding: 25px;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 34px;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a {
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:before,
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:before {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 24px 0 0 24px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFC937;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 24px 24px 0 0;
  border-color: #FFA523 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li:last-child > a:before,
.b-breadcrumbs > li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 24px;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a > span:before,
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a > span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  left: 0;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a > span:before {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0 24px 24px 0;
  border-color: transparent #FFC937 transparent transparent;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a > span:after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 24px 24px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #FFA523 transparent;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:hover:before {
  border-left-color: red;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:hover:after {
  border-top-color: red;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:hover > span:before {
  border-right-color: red;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:hover > span:after {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b-breadcrumbs">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант 2** - с использованием clip-path

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-breadcrumbs {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    background: #271E19;
    padding: 25px;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 201, 55, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 165, 35, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 50%, 90% 100%, 0 100%, 10% 50%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 50%, 90% 100%, 0 100%, 10% 50%);
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li:first-child > a{
    padding-left: 15px;
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 50%, 90% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 50%, 90% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li:last-child > a{
    padding-right: 15px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 10% 50%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 10% 50%);
}
.b-breadcrumbs > li > a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b-breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не кроссбраузерный, в мозилле 2-й вариант отображается ввиде обычных прямоугольников, в 1-м по центру линия

Comment: Я это знаю - во втором варианте поддержка браузерами http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: @Alex - 1 вариант поправил

Answer (score 4):

Сам треугольник можно получить задавая различные цвета границам разных сторон элемента, а добавить к элементу - используя псевдоэлементы :before :after

```css
   .block {
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    width: 120px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
   }
   .block::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px; /* Положение треугольника */
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid green; 
   }
   .second::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    border: 10px solid green;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="block">
  Концепция
  </div>
  <div class="block second">
 Реализация
  </div>
```

Comment: Этот ответ тянет максимум на комментарий. Предоставьте более развернутый ответ и приложите примеры кода. И не надо давать ответы-ссылки, потому что спустя какое-то время ссылка может стать нерабочей и от вашего ответа не будет смысла.

Comment: Согласен по всем пунктам. Спасибо.